# c# webclient download image fail

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

We upgraded from windows server 2012 to windows server 2019.
I'm using webclient to download images during a user session.
Use to work perfectly and works locally when I run it.
When I move the source code to windows server 2019 it fails with the standard **The underlying connection was closed:**

Using .Net 4.6   Using Security Protocol Tls12.
I'm extremely baffled by what is causing the issue

```
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                using (var web_client = new WebClient())
                {
                web_client.DownloadFile(file_url, download_file_path_with_name);
                }
```

Does anyone have some other suggestions.  I tried with Exter100Continue = true with same results.

Comment: I think you must be give permission in windows server for access the fileURL

Comment: Have you tried TLS13? I recall one being deprecated a year or two back but cant recall which.

Comment: And what version of the .net framework is it running on? https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` is unrelated. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` is only used in a System like Windows 7, where the default is not TLS1.2. In Windows 10, it's useless, unless you want to explicitly enable an older protocol (because some older but known service needs it), or explicitly include TLS1.3. Download [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (free) and check whether you have something disabled that you shouldn't and verify the Cipher Suites requested in the handshake.

Comment: Test/analyze a Web Site with [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to determine what Security is in place. If you have Proxy Servers in between, check those too or bypass to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some big changes in the versions and cipher suites from 2012 to 2019.

First:
I would recommend that you just allow the OS to decide which Security Protocol to use (it will negotiate TLS version and cipher suite with the server that hosts your image). Here is a [good article about TLS versioning and .NET versions and OS versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Second:
I would run something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) locally on your server to see where the web request is failing (I'm guessing the TLS handshake fails). Fiddler will provide alot more detail about your web requests at the packet level.

Comment: I took Jimi advice first.  Configuration was good when running IIS Crypto..    For a patch since I'm downloading images from the same website is to remove the 's' from https  to download the picture.  That worked.    I'm not a fan of the solution but I'm the only developer/manager here so I take my victories where I can.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, would be nice to eventually get back to using that 's' so that your communications are encrypted. Maybe a backlog item!

Answer (score 0):

If you set a user agent in your web client instance would it have worked?

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"